# How to use the StringComparison in c# (CA1307)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, string-comparison, fxcop

My aim is to omit the data which *author_name* starts with **pipeline** and *author_email* starts with **pipeline@gmail.com** If the project name starts with **ej2** or **Ej2**.

I have below code. This code worked perfectly what I expected.

```
if ((author_name != "pipeline" && author_email != "pipeline@gmail.com") && 
    (projectName.StartsWith("ej2") == false || projectName.StartsWith("Ej2") == false))
{
  // some operations
}
```

My FxCop said to below violation to use the above method.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning **CA1307**  Because the behavior of 'string.StartsWith(string)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings, replace this call in 'GetProjectDetailsByApi.DevelopmentBranchStatus(List)' with a call to 'string.StartsWith(string, StringComparison)'. If the result of 'string.StartsWith(string, StringComparison)' will be displayed to the user, such as when sorting a list of items for display in a list box, specify 'StringComparison.CurrentCulture' or 'StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase' as the 'StringComparison' parameter. If comparing case-insensitive identifiers, such as file paths, environment variables, or registry keys and values, specify 'StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase'. Otherwise, if comparing case-sensitive identifiers, specify 'StringComparison.Ordinal'.

So I changed my code like below. But I got only

```
if (author_name.Equals("pipeline", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false
    && author_email.Equals("pipeline@gmail.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false 
    && projectName.StartsWith("ej2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
{
   //mY code
}
```

But above code filter all **ej2** project. But I want to filter only the project which have the **author_name** and **author_email** is **pipeline** and **pipeline@gmail.com** respectively.

If I change the condition `projectName.StartsWith("ej2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == **true**` means, It gives only the project which starts only **ej2**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that you're doing a case-insensitive comparison on one string (`ej2`) instead of a case sensitive comparison (using `StringComparison.Ordinal`) on both strings (`ej2` and `Ej2`) that you want to filter (at least that's the change I see from your first to the second condition).

Something like this seems like a FxCop-safe version of your original condition (Note: I used the "not" operator (`!`) instead of `== false` to save some typing):

```
if (!author_name.Equals("pipeline", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    && !author_email.Equals("pipeline@gmail.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    && !projectName.StartsWith("ej2", StringComparison.Ordinal) 
    && !projectName.StartsWith("Ej2", StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
   // do something here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this condition filtered all the project which starts with ej2.  But I need to filter like If the project name starts with ej2 or Ej2  and author_name is pipeline and author_email is pipeline@gmail.com means I don`t need that data.

Comment: I mean, I need to omit the data which have author_name =  pipeline and author_email = pipeline@gmail.com only in the project starts with Ej2 or ej2

Comment: This condition in my answer (was) a replica of the original one you said was working, except it has the `StringComparison` parts added. However, I've updated the code to change the `||` to `&&`. The reason is that, for all projects the last two conditions (which were grouped together) will always evaluate to `true`. If a project name is `"ej2"`, then the second check for `"Ej2"` will be true. Since `false || true == true`, then no matter the name, the last set of conditions isn't doing anything. My only question is, how is it possible that the first one you showed was doing what you wanted?

Answer (score 4):

> Omit the data which have author_name = pipeline and author_email = pipeline@gmail.com only in the project starts with Ej2 or ej2

**Try This :**

```
if(!author_name.Equals("pipeline",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !author_email.Equals("pipeline@gmail.com ",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    if(projectName.StartsWith("Ej2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // do Your Operations
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it with

`#pragma warning disable CA1307 // Specify StringComparison`

and `#pragma warning restore CA1307 // Specify StringComparison`

Comment: Thx, I was looking for this because I can't use StringComparisson in Linq to Entity